# Learned eBGP routes not distributed to iBGP neighbors

Tags: cisco, routing, router, bgp

I have (in GNS3) three Cisco 3640s running 12.4(23) connected in series (R1 -> R2 -> R3).
R1 and R2 are eBGP peers, R2 and R3 are iBGP peers.
R1 advertises network 192.168.1.0/24. R2 receives this route, but does not advertise it to R3.

Shouldn't routes learned from eBGP be advertised to iBGP?

Here's the full configuration as entered:

```
loop0(R1)s0/0 <--> s0/0(R2)s0/1 <--> s0/1(R3)

R1:
configure terminal
interface s0/0
ip address 172.16.1.1 255.255.255.252
no shutdown
interface loopback0
ip address  192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
router bgp 1
neighbor 172.16.1.2 remote-as 2
network 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0

R2:
configure terminal
interface s0/0
ip address 172.16.1.2 255.255.255.252
no shutdown
interface s0/1
ip address 172.16.1.5 255.255.255.252
no shutdown
router bgp 2
neighbor 172.16.1.1 remote-as 1
neighbor 172.16.1.6 remote-as 2

R3:
configure terminal
interface s0/1
ip address 172.16.1.6  255.255.255.252
no shutdown
router bgp 2
neighbor 172.16.1.5 remote-as 2
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming you have no IGP configured (such as EIGRP / OSPF / ISIS / RIP), then the simplest explanation is that R3 hasn't got a route to 192.168.1.0/24's next-hop when the iBGP update arrives at R3.

```
loop0(R1)s0/0 <-----------> s0/0(R2)s0/1 <-------------> s0/1(R3)
    AS 1                       AS 2                        AS 2

              --------->                  ----------->
              Prefix: 192.168.1.0/24      Prefix: 192.168.1.0/24
              AS-path: 1                  AS-path: 1
              Next-hop: 172.16.1.1        Next-hop: 172.16.1.1
              *via eBGP*                  *via iBGP*
```

Since iBGP doesn't reset the next-hop when it receives the update from R1, 192.168.1.0/24's next-hop (172.16.1.1) has to be reachable (see [Why routers ignore BGP paths](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk365/technologies_tech_note09186a0080094431.shtml#background) for more details).

The most basic way to test this is to configure a static on R3:

```
ip route 172.16.1.0 0.0.0.3 172.16.1.5 name BAD_HACK_FOR_IBGP
```

That's obviously the wrong solution, but it's a dead-simple test to illustrate why things are broken (keep in mind that you may need to wait a bit for the BGP next-hop scanner to run before 192.168.1.0/24's route is installed).

There are two possible solutions that come to mind, but only one really makes sense in most networks...

- **Best solution**: Configure an IGP... pick any IGP you like, and advertise 172.16.1.0/30 throughout AS 2 in that IGP
- *Optional solution*: Configure the peering session between R2 and R3 to set [`next-hop-self`](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/iproute_bgp/command/reference/irg_bgp3.html#wp1108213)

Next-hop reachability is one of the most basic issues when understanding BGP; almost everyone runs into this issue when they're experimenting with the protocol.

Comment: Excellent explanation. I was unaware that iBGP passes the next-hop unmodified.

Comment: Mike, could you provide an example of when you *wouldn't* want to use `next-hop-self` (other than due to already having an IGP advertising the eBGP peer's next-hop address)?   I was initially going to make another question for this, but figured it would be an easy add to your answer.  Recently having been labbing out BGP, and I keep running into this, it makes me curious as to *why* `next-hop-self` wasn't the default behavior.

Comment: I can add information about this, but it might take a few days before I get time.  Short story:  IGP cost to the BGP next hop is part of the default eBGP path selection algorithm

Answer (score 0):

You should have to anounce your connected interfaces on R2. because the only network 192.168.1.0 does not now what is the next hop. 
You can checking with **"show ip bgp"** on R3.

As you can see 192.168.1.0 in R3 bgp table but not inserted to routing table. Because it does not know what is the next-hop

**Solution:**

1. Redistribute connected interfaces on R2
2. Say EBGP neighbor that who is next hop as "**neighbor 172.16.1.2 next-hop-self**" on **R1**.